# Retrieving deleted files with a Github rollback

Tags: github

I tried roll-backing my commits to save some files that were deleted from reasons that I do not know.

Upon rolling back, and before I commited my changes, I did a `git status` and this what was written in my shell.

[image]

All the files that says `deleted` are the files I would like to recover. Before I do anything silly and delete everything, is there any way to retrieve these files?

This is what I mean by "before commit."

I apologize before hand. I am a new user to Github, and I am a bit paranoid about not being able to recover these files, since they mean a lot to me.

[image]

Upon rolling back, I have this as my `sync` button. When I do press it, it tells me I have unmerged conflicts.

[image]

Comment: It seems committing after rolling back did not seem to give my files back..

Comment: "roll back" is not a git term, so it is hard to understand what you mean; did you "roll back" on github or on your computer? If your computer, what command did you give?

Comment: It says right on the screen you show: if you do not want to stage the listed changes, reset to HEAD. Did you try that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that was committed is safe, as long as you have a branch or tag that includes it, local or remote.

> All the files that says deleted are the files I would like to recover

You can get back specific files using `git checkout`, for example:

```
git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file1 path/to/file2
```

Another option is to undo all the listed changes at once:

```
git reset --hard
```

That said, whenever you use the `--hard` flag of `git reset`, be careful: it wipes out all pending changes. So if you have some changes that were never committed or staged, they will be gone. In this particular case it seems this is what you want, but in general be careful when using this.

Comment: That is a bit strong. Even if he detaches the head he can recover the branch.

Comment: @matt I guess I wasn't clear enough. I updated it now. Better?